# How do I hide folders from the Site Hierarchy in SharePoint Services

Tags: sharepoint, wss

How do I configure the Site Hierarchy on the left hand side of a SharePoint Services 3.0 site to NOT show folders?

We have thousands of folders and it takes ages to load the page!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean the Quick Launch bar.  If not then just leave me a comment so I can update the answer.

In a nutshell you want to configure navigation from the site settings page.  You an quickly go in and tell it to NOT display any child sites.  For detail instructions checkout this [page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101181901033.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Site Actions, Site Settings, Modify All.
In 'Look and Feel' click on 'Tree View'.
In 'Tree View' uncheck Enable Tree View.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the SPWeb.Navigation class to remove all the undesired items from the quick launch bar. For more information check these classes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation_members.aspx

Good luck.